# Spring MVC handle multiple REST commands in a single HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want to be able to generically handle a mass of commands as a single `POST` request represented as a map of `URL => Body`, that processes each command via its matching `RequestMapping` and returns a map of `URL => Response`.

Request:

```
{
   "/api/things/34?huh=wat": {
       "method": "GET"
   },
   "/api/dogs": {
       "method": "POST",
       "body": /* some dog-esque json */
   }
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "/api/things/34?huh=wat": {
       "response": /* thing-esque json */
   },
   "/api/dogs": {
       "response": /* some error json */
   }
}
```

I am not concerned too much with the shape of the request/response objects, I just don't know how to handle this in Spring.

Comment: The cult of REST is making you do terrible things. Have a look at [JSON-RPC2](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification), specifically the ability to batch multiple method calls into a single request.

Comment: @dnault This looks like something that would work well, too. Is there existing support for this in Spring?

Comment: Not built into Spring, but there's [jsonrpc4j](https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j) which offers Spring integration.

Comment: Similar question is asked. I have answered it there. See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48070529/1578559](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48070529/1578559)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the client should be splitting the individual requests up and sending them one at at a time. Think about it this way, what happens if the `POST` succeeds but the `GET` returns a 500 server error? Do you take the status of the whole request to be 500? And what about the `POST`, does it now need to be rolled back?

Comment: I would include this information in the response. The batch itself would always return `200` unless something really blew up. The goal of this approach is to reduce the number of HTTP requests, they are currently being sent individually.

Comment: What benefit will batching them provide? It may reduce network traffic, but I'm not sure if grouping unrelated requests together is a good idea. Your spring config may have certain interceptors, return value handlers etc which you will still have to run yourself and that may be error prone.

Comment: Reducing the number of requests is the entire goal. We use nothing inside Spring besides MVC controllers for our api. I am not really concerned with how error prone it will be, I just want to know if and how I can write this batch-style endpoint once and have it work with all my existing endpoints.